# How to fix styling problems with ttk button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I have a TTK Button in my app and I want to style it but the problem is that some of these styles don't work. Here is my style for the button:

```
style.configure("Menu.TButton", font=("Times New Roman", 20), width=300, padx=20, anchor=W, background="#21252B", foreground="#fff", activebackground="#BD93F9", bd=0)
```

But with this style, the `foreground` just puts a white overlay on the button, `background` doesn't work at all, `activebackground` also doesn't work at all, and `padx` also doesn't work.

So are the names for these styles different or am I doing something wrong?

if it helps here is the code for the button:

```
home_button = Button(menu_frame, style="Menu.TButton", text="Home")
home_button.grid(column=0, row=1)
```

and here is how to looks:

[image: button]

Comment: Which OS are you using? Does it change something if you add `style.theme_use("clam")` before the `style.configure(...)` part?

Comment: I am on windows but I don't want to use themes in my app so is there a way to do it without themes

Comment: Maybe if you use a `tk.Button` instead of `ttk.Button` and no style

Comment: Windows default theme for ttk widget does not allow to change the background of buttons and other widgets.

Comment: @j_4321 actually I have used a menu frame and I was successfully able to change the background using styles

Comment: You can change the background of a `ttk.Frame` with a style but not of a `ttk.Button` . In my previous comment, I meant that you cannot change the background of some widgets with `style.configure(..)` when using the default Windows theme, not all of them.

Comment: @j_4321 I fixed the problem using `style.theme_use("clam")` and `relief=FLAT` but how do I change the activebackground and the color when my mouse hovers over it?

Comment: Use `style.map`, you will find some examples online

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here some options you can play around:

```
toolstyle = ttk.Style()  
toolstyle.theme_use("clam")    # "default", "alt" .....

toolstyle.configure('TButton',                                           
                     background="black",
                     foreground="white", 
                     borderwidth=1,
                     bordercolor="red",
                     lightcolor="yellow",
                     darkcolor="purple",
                     focuscolor="none", 
                     font=("Bahnschrift", 14),
                     width=2)
toolstyle.map('TButton',
                    background=[("pressed", "white"),
                                ("active", "grey")],
                    borderwidth=[("active", 0)],
                    bordercolor=[("active", "blue")],
                    lightcolor=[("active", "purple")],
                    darkcolor=[("active", "black")],
                    foreground=[("pressed", "black"),
                                ("active", "red")]
                           )
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @j_4321 I figured out how to fix this.

Default Windows theme doesn't allow the changing of button styles so to change the button style you need to use the themes provided by ttk like: `style.theme_use("clam")`

After doing that you can change button styles using configure.

To Change the color of the button when the user clicks or hovers over it you can use `style.map` like this:

```
style.map("Menu.TButton", background=[('!active', "#21252B"), ('pressed', '#BD93F9'), ("active", "#282C34")], foreground=[('!active', '#fff'), ('pressed', '#fff'), ('active', '#fff')])
```